# Restful web application security

Tags: security, rest, web-applications, playframework-1.x

I was wondering a bit about security of my web application. I have two questions and I hope you can help me with them

I am using a play framework (which supports rest); some of my REST routes look like this:

```
GET  /mailbox/user/{userId} Application.getMailboxMessages
```

I have two questions regarding to that case

1 . does placing the `userId` in my route make it a security risk? (does getting the `userId` from the session in the server and not passing the `userId` at all is what I should do?)

The first url leads me to place the `userId` in my javascript file.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"/mailbox/user/"+window.userId, 
    success : function() {....}
})
```

2 . does placing `userId` in the javascript is a security risk?

3 . also what happens with other user ids I interact with using ajax, should I do something about them also?
for example:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST", 
   url : "/sendMessage/userFrom/"window.userId+"/userTo/"+ someTargetUserVar ,
   success: function() {//update some gui here}
})
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad. 1. placing userId is basically ok, it is not security risk (but you can obviously get it from session in the backend, sometimes URL convension is to use link like /mailbox/user/self

Ad. 2. As above, it is ok.

Ad. 3. If a given request is valid only for logged users then either validate that and return error code for id of a non-current user or don't pass id in the url, just get it from session and then use /mailbox/user/self to make clear your intension for API user.

Comment: ok , so i can pass the userId to the server, but need to validate it with the server session for the current connected user ?

Comment: Yep, that's the way to go. Or just get id from session.